# Как растянуть столбцы в qtableView чтобы они заняли все поле виджета вне зависимости от контекста

Tags: c++, qt, таблицы

Как растянуть столбцы в qtableView чтобы они заняли все поле виджета вне зависимости от контекста?

Еще охота автоматическое выравнивание при перемотки.

Версия qt 4.7.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ui->table->horizontalHeader()->setStretchLastSection(true); // растянуть последнюю секцию (это свойство можно задать и просто в дизайнере)
ui->table->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(2, QHeaderView::Stretch); // растянуть конкретную секцию
```

также можно растянуть и последнюю запись вертикально:

```
ui->table->verticalHeader()->setStretchLastSection(true);
```

при этом растяжение конкретной секции можно устанавливать только после того как таблица заполнена данными (иначе у нее будет отсутствовать horizontalHeader что приведет к исключению)

Answer (score 2):

Для Qt5+ воспользуйтесь методом QHeaderView::setSectionResizeMode() с аргументом растяжки QHeaderView::Stretch:

```
qtableView->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::Stretch);
```

Для старых версий `QHeaderView::setResizeMode(QHeaderView::Stretch);`